# Why this paradox while calculating eigen values for T*T?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let T be an operator on the vector space V and let λ<sub>1</sub>, ..... , λ<sub>n</sub> be it's eigen values including multiplicity .

Lets find the eigen values for the operator T*T then ( where T* refers to the adjoint operator .
< u,v > denotes inner product of u and v )

< Tv , Tv > = < λv, λv > 
                 = λλ<sub>°</sub> < v , v >
                 = |λ|<sup>2</sup> < v , v>

( where λ° is the conjugate of λ . )

=> < T*T v, v> = < |λ|<sup>2</sup> v, v >

=> T*T has an eigen value |λ|<sup>2</sup> for the same eigen vector v which T possesses.

This can be inferred because :

Suppose f is a linear functional on V . Then there is a unique vector v in V such that f(u) =  for all u in V.

( A linear functional on V is a linear map from V to the scalars F , As sheldon axler pg 117 says it ) The above argument must imply then that : T*T v = |λ|<sup>2</sup> v  ( Doesn't this imply v is an eigen vector of T*T ? )

now, lets consider a matrix $$M(T) = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 \\
0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$

[ 3   1 ]<sup>T</sup> is clearly an eigen vector with eigen value = 2 .

M(T* T ) =\begin{bmatrix}  1 & 0 \\ 3 & 2 \end{bmatrix}  multiplied by \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 \\
0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}

= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 \\
3 & 13
\end{bmatrix}

M(T* T ) times [ 3   1 ]<sup>T</sup> should produce a vector equal to

4 [ 3   1 ]<sup>T</sup>

however , \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 \\
3 & 13
\end{bmatrix} multiplied by  [ 3  1 ]T = [ 6  22 ]T.

Can you please advise why this paradox exists ? Am i making a mistake somewhere ? 
Thanks

Comment: The line "$\langle T^*Tv,v\rangle=\langle|\lambda|^2 v,v\rangle$" does not prove that $v$ is an eigenvector of $T^*T$, even if $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$.

Comment: Thanks . but, suppose f is a linear functional on V . Then there is a unique vector v in V such that f(u) = <u,v> for all u in V. ( A linear functional on V is a linear map from V to the scalars F , As sheldon axler pg 117 says it ) 

The above argument must imply then that :
T*T v = |λ|^2 v
Doesn't this imply v is an eigen vector of T*T ?

Comment: There is no $u$ here at stake.

Comment: does this mean that the equation < T*T v , v > = <|λ|^2 v , v >
may not mean that T*T v = |λ|^2 v ?

Comment: Exactly. See also Berci's answer.

Comment: Thank you. I am thinking over this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your example shows, it is *not true* that $T^*T$ has the *same* eigenvectors. Since, $Tv=\lambda v$, this would mean that $v$ is also an eigenvector of $T^*$, but this is only guaranteed by $T=T^*$. Instead, we only have $v^*T^*=(Tv)^*=\bar\lambda v^*$, which is irrelevant for eigenvectors of $T^*$.

Comment: thanks. But, in the proof above, it has been shown that < T*T v, v> = < |λ|^2 v, v > .
Since, the result is not valid, there must be something wrong with this proof . What can be wrong here ?

Comment: The non precise implicit and explicit handling of *quantifiers*. We indeed have $\langle T^*Tv,v\rangle=\langle|\lambda|^2v,v\rangle$ for the particular eigenvector $v$ of $T$. But we don't have $\langle T^*Tv,u\rangle=\langle |\lambda|^2v,u\rangle$ *for all* $u$, which would indeed mean $T^*Tv=|\lambda|^2v$, but as your example shows, this is not the case.

Comment: Thank you . I am thinking over this. :)

Comment: got it ! Thanks Berci and @Christian Blatter .